# Webpack 4 ./src directory not found

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I am trying to split the webpack config to base, dev and prod configs. Here is my entry section of `webpack.base.babel.js` file

```
module.exports = options => ({
   mode: options.mode,
   entry: options.entry,
   output: Object.assign(
     {
      // Compile into js/build.js
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
      publicPath: '/',
     },
     options.output,
   ), // Merge with env dependent settings
```

Here is the entry section of `webpackdev.babel.js` file:

```
module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  mode: 'development',

  // Add hot reloading in development
  entry: [
    require.resolve('react-app-polyfill/ie11'),
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js'), 
  ],

  // Don't use hashes in dev mode for better performance
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
  },
```

My start script in package.json looks like: `"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"`

But when I run npm start I get the bellow error:

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'

. I am on Windows 10. Could anybody explain what's wrong with my webpack config. I am specifying the entry file as `app/app.js` but still webpack is defaulting to `src/index.js`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hand in your webpack config explicitely by changing your npm `start` script to:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpackdev.babel.js"
```

Webpack searches for [`webpack.config.js`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) in the root folder automatically.  Starting with v4, Webpack also claims to be a zero config bundler, so it will use [opinionated defaults](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/), if no config can be located. E.g.:

- entry point of your project is assumed to be `src/index`
- output will be put in `dist/main.js`
- production [mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) will minify and do optimizations

Your config seems to be right, but Webpack can't find it and assumes the default entry, thus your error `Can't resolve './src'`.